# using Storyboard change navigationbar style and color with (CRGradientNavigationBar)?

Tags: ios

---

project sdk version: ios  > 7.0

FITST: I want user  '`CRGradientNavigationBar`' in my project.. but i use storyboard layout...

LINK: [CRGradientNavigationBar](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar%3E)

The effect can not be achieved `CRGradientNavigationBar`.. 
So, please help me ......

---

```
  NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)UIColorFromRGB(0xf16149).CGColor, (id)UIColorFromRGB(0xf14959).CGColor, nil];

  [[CRGradientNavigationBar appearance] setBarTintGradientColors:colors];
```

'is something wrong ??'****

Answer (score 2):

To use [CRGradientNavigationBar](https://github.com/chroman/CRGradientNavigationBar) in a Storyboard, you could do the followings 2 things:

1) Create/ Embed a Navigation Controller in your Storyboard. Then go the left side menu (Document Outline) select Navigation Bar on the just created Navigation Controller and then on the right Menu on the Identity Inspector go to Custom Class and use: CRGradientNavigationBar. For the last thing, make sure that you have selected the NavigationController.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVFOQ.jpg

2) In your ViewController use for example:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor orangeColor].CGColor, nil];
        [(CRGradientNavigationBar *)[self.navigationController navigationBar] setBarTintGradientColors:colors];
    }
```